# Camunda JUnit not working with Delegate class referenced as Delegate Expression

Tags: camunda

I am trying to run a simple Junit test case where the service task refers a delegate class using Delegate Expression ${calculateInterestService}.

[image]

When I run the test case, it gives the following error.

[main] ERROR org.camunda.bpm.engine.context - ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: Unknown property used in expression: ${calculateInterestService}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'calculateInterestService'

But the same test case works fine, when I refer the delegate as a Java class.

What am I missing here. Please advise.

Comment: If you run a plain Java unit test without Spring, then no Spring context is available. Hence the engine does not know how to evaluate the expression / where to find the bean you are referencing with this expression. It can find and instantiate a Java class though. That's why it works with a Java class but not with an expression. To solve this, Camunda has a mock context in which beans can be registered and looked up by name/expression by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a Camunda 7 plain Java unit test (as opposed to a SpringBootTest) then no Spring context in which the engine can evaluate expressions / lookup beans is available. Plain Java classes can still be found and instantiated, but but expressions referencing a bean cannot be resolved. Hence Java class works and expression does not.
Camunda offers a Mock context in which you can register beans. It is documented here:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/testing/#resolving-beans-without-spring-cdi

So you need something like

```
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.runtime.ProcessInstance;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.Deployment;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.mock.Mocks;
import org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.test.helper.AbstractProcessEngineRuleTest;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.assertions.bpmn.BpmnAwareTests.*;

@Deployment(resources = "process.bpmn")
public class ProcessTest extends AbstractProcessEngineRuleTest {

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    Mocks.register("calculateInterestService", new CalculateInterestDelegate());
  }

  @Test
  public void testHappyPath() {

    ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("example-process", withVariables("myVar", "myVarValue"));
    assertThat(pi).isEnded();
  }

}
```

Here is a complete example project with a plain Java test (faster):
https://github.com/rob2universe/flexible-delegate/blob/main/src/test/java/com/camunda/example/test/ProcessTest.java
and a SpringBootTest (slower because it bootstraps complete Spring):
https://github.com/rob2universe/flexible-delegate/blob/main/src/test/java/com/camunda/example/test/SpringBootProcessTest.java